# XKB: Hyper_L and Hyper_R

Tags: linux, keyboard, xkb, xmonad

I'm running XMonad as my WM and I've been very inspired by this [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=70IxjLEmomg).
In short, what I'd like to achieve is having my right `\` key when pressed continually, act as a `Hyper_R` and the left `Tab` act as a `Hyper_L`.

The video's creator talks about a setup using some xkb configuration along with xcape. While xcape was easy to get going on my system, the xkb bit has me confused. I tried getting in touch with Ethan (the creator of the video) but I understand he probably doesn't have the time to answer individual questions all the time.

Also the linked Github repository doesn't seem to have anything of the sort of an xkb configuration.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to achieve this?

Comment: Don't believe this is directly related to XMonad, so you might get a better answer if you asked about the xkb directly. None the less this might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44977410/in-xmonad-how-to-remap-capslock-to-ctrl